# Adding custom routes to an mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm creating a system that users can add project information to.  Part of the system has sub forms that hang off of the project. I'm trying to get my head around how to set up the routing and wondered if it's possible to create routes like below.

```
/project/
/project/12345
/project/12345/bid - id is the same as the project e.g 12345
/project/12345/bid/create - id is the same as the project e.g 12345
/project/12345/bid/edit - id is the same as the project e.g 12345
```

Is this a good idea, or would it be better to do:

```
/bid
/bid/create - id is the same as the project e.g 12345
/bid/12345 - id is the same as the project e.g 12345
/bid/12345/edit - id is the same as the project e.g 12345
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a big difference. But I would advise you to use first version. Something else but `/project`s can appear later. Also such urls are more obvious and self-describing.

To implement that take a look at [attribute routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/). It will meet your needs perfectly.

Example:

```
[RoutePrefix("project")]
public class ProjectController : Controller
{
    // eg: /project
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Index() { ... }

    // eg: /project/1234
    [Route("{projectID:int}")]
    public ActionResult Project(int projectID) { ... }

    // eg: /project/1234/bid
    [Route("{projectID:int}/bid")]
    public ActionResult Bid(int projectID) { ... }

    // eg: /project/1234/bid/create
    [Route("{projectID:int}/bid/create")]
    Public ActionResult CreateBid(int projectID) { ... }

    // so on
}
```

And don't forget to register such routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // other routes if you need

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like following unless it's a public website then I will add small description in the URL for SEO.

> /bid/789
>
> /bid/create
>
> /bid/edit/12345

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```